# PHP / MySQL - current date/time in timezone

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, timezone

How do request the date/time in PHP or MySQL within a timezone?
I'd rather do it on the PHP side, but also would like to know if its possible in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
```

Or per connection:

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can return **Unix time**, which is **universal time**, like that:

- in MySQL ([`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)):

  ```
  SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
  ```
- in PHP ([`time()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)):

  ```
  echo time();
  ```

If you want the **time in your current time zone**, you can do it like that:

- in MySQL ([`NOW()` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)):

  ```
  SELECT NOW();
  ```
- in PHP (for available formats refer to [`date()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)):

  ```
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  ```

Does it meet your needs?